# Focusing 'multiple' HTML input fields with jQuery or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, focus

Hi again :)
I'm using jQuery script to show/hide some content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.toggleButton').click(function() {
    var id = this.id.replace('toggleButton', '');
    $('#content' + id).toggle();
});
</script>
```

Since I'm using PHP, I am iterating through few items and each of them has a button to show/hide its content. My content is actually a form with few input fields. In each item, first field of my form has a same name (let's say 'line1').
What I would like to do is when I click on an item and open its content, to take a focus on input field 'line1'. When I click on other item to take a focus on its 'line1' field, and so on...
Preferably with jQuery because I suppose it would be simpler, but javascript solution would be also great :)

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I will attach a part of code which is  that I need to show and hide... Maybe it will be of some help... I am using codeigniter, so not to be confused by some functions :)

```
echo "<div class=\"toggleButton\" id=\"toggleButton".$item['id']."\">CLICK TO OPEN</div>";
echo "<div class=\"content\" id=\"content".$item['id']."\" style=\"display:none;\">";
echo form_open('title/add'); // codeigniter's open form
for ($i = 1; $i <= $item['rows']; $i++) {
    echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"line\" id=\"line".($i)."\">".br();
}
echo form_submit('submit', 'submit'); // codeigniter's submit for button
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: thanks for edit ninja dude :) i have that line correctly written in my script, seems it was just a typo here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your last line to:

```
$('#content' + id).toggle().find('input').first().focus()
```

Comment: Thanks for help but for some reason this ultra-simple and logical solution won't work in my case :( Do you have some idea why this is not working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780288/jquery-validation-using-the-class-instead-of-the-name-value

Comment: ok, I 'upgraded' jQuery version and now it works as expected... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you try giving common  class name  and call function based on class name

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, I'm total noob in jQuery... All my divs have 'class' attribute and I have tried this: $('.content').find('input').first().focus(); but this won't work either...

Comment: hello zod and thanks for help! unfortunately this solution is not working either :( i have tried few combinations - for example, $('.content').find('input').focus(); will focus each 'submit' button in my forms. $('#line1').focus(); will focus correctly but only when i show first hidden div... in second one, third and so on, line1 will not be focused. $('.line').focus(); will focus each LAST input field in my forms... but i cannot make it to focus on first field, no way :( what am i doing wrong here??