# jQuery validation on a checkbox group using class

Tags: jquery, validation, class, checkbox

My question is very similar to jQuery Validation using the class instead of the name value[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780288/jquery-validation-using-the-class-instead-of-the-name-value). I want to validate a checkbox group, such that at least one needs to be checked. By default, both checkboxes are checked, but I want to ensure the user doesn't uncheck both. The checkboxes are

```
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="channel" name="web" checked />
    <label for="web" class="check">Web</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="channel" name="mobile" checked />
    <label for="mobile" class="check">Mobile</label>
    </div>
```

The jquery I have is:

```
$("#searchForm").validate({
    rules:{
            ...
            ...
            ...
    }
});

$(".channel").rules("add", {  
    required: true, 
     minlength: 1

});
```

However, this doesn't work quite as expected. If I check neither of the boxes or only the second one (mobile), the form won't submit and I get an error message on the first one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'd use jQuery Validation for something like this, but if you just want to make sure that there is **at least one** checked checkbox in any group (whether that be class, or any other attribute), you can just check the length of any proper selector.

```
if ($('.channel:checked').length == 0) {
    // validation fails
}
```

**EDIT**

Without using Validation, you can stop the submit by doing something like:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    if ($('.channel:checked').length == 0) {
        // validation fails, so stop submit
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm using jquery validation for the rest of the form, and use the validation function to handle the form submission as well - if the form passes validation, it disables the submit button and submits the form.

Comment: Yeap, that's what I was thinking you were trying to do. Check out the updated answer above; that should do what you were trying to do without having to deal with explicitly setting jQuery validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the jQuery plugin Validation, you can set up your HTML like this:

```
<form class="commentForm" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <label for="transportation">Transportation</label>
            <input class="ccheckbox" type="checkbox" name="transportation" value="Bike">I have a bike <br />
            <input class="ccheckbox" type="checkbox" name="transportation" value="Car">I have a car <br />
            <input class="ccheckbox" type="checkbox" name="transportation" value="Walk">I walk
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

You should add the **"message"** and the **"rules"** options to your form validation. Use the **"depends"** property to set up a conditional test that will test for the presence of checked boxes.

```
        $(".commentForm").validate({
            messages: {
                transportation: {
                    required: "How do you get around?"
                },
            },
            rules: {
                transportation:{
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element) {
                            return $('input[name="transportation"]:checked').length == 0;
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
        });
```