# JQuery validate plugin - can't validate classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use the jQuery validate plugin to validate classes instead of ID's. Despite the many threads which seem close to answering this issue - I can't get any of them to work. I simply have a form that has a lot of dynamically generated repeating form fields, so naturally I can't add rules for the ID's because there's no knowing how many of them there will be. So, instead, I would like to just target the class on the input field.

```
<input type="text" id="name1" class="fileName" />
<input type="text" id="name2" class="fileName" />
<input type="text" id="name3" class="fileName" />
<input type="text" id="name4" class="fileName" />
```

How do I target 'fileName' class? I've tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.validator.addClassRules({
        fileName:{
        required: true
    }
    });
    $("#myForm").validate();
});
```

But this does not work at all :(

Any ideas? Anyone?

Comment: where is the rest of your form ?

Answer (score 10):

You need to specify a `name` attribute on each `input` element for validator to pick it up:

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" id="name1" class="fileName" name="name1" />
    <input type="text" id="name2" class="fileName" name="name2"/>
    <input type="text" id="name3" class="fileName" name="name3"/>
    <input type="text" id="name4" class="fileName" name="name4"/>
</form>
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Nbcj9/

Comment: btw inputs should not be in a form without a parent 8 ^ )

Comment: @mcgrailm: Agreed, I just assumed the OP had them in a form :)

Answer (score 6):

According to the docs, this should work:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules('classNameHere', {
  required: true
});
```

Then you can determine whether the fields are valid by calling:

```
$('.fileName').valid();
```

Here's a link to [the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/)

Comment: The class name shouldn't begin with a period.

Answer (score -3):

what about:

```
$(".fileName").validate();
```

Comment: `validate` is called on a form element... How would this work?