# Add Same Rule Multiple Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to add the same rules to html input elements with this naming convention:

```
name="elements[1]"
name="elements[2]"
```

I'm using jQuery and jQuery Validation Plugin:

```
var elements = $("#elementsFieldset :input");
$.each(elements, function(i, element) {
    element.rules('add', {
    required: true,
    number: true
});
```

But I'm afraid that *element* is not the kind of object jQuery expects for adding rules.
I'm receiving:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'rules'
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validation Plugin - adding rules that apply to multiple fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829030/jquery-validation-plugin-adding-rules-that-apply-to-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `$(this)` instead of  `element`.

`element` is HTML JavaScript Object.

to add rules you need jQuery Object i.e `$(this)`

```
var elements = $("#elementsFieldset :input");
$.each(elements, function(i, element) {
    $(this).rules('add', {
    required: true,
    number: true
});
```

or even better

```
var elements = $("#elementsFieldset :input");
    elements.each(function(){
        $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        number: true
    });
```

**Updated**

Below code works for one element only if you want to apply rule for more than one element use `.each()` as used in above example.

```
$("#elementsFieldset :input").rules("add", { 
  required:true,  
  number:true
});
```

Read [jQuery Validation Plugin - adding rules that apply to multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829030/jquery-validation-plugin-adding-rules-that-apply-to-multiple-fields/9056425#9056425) commented by [**Sparky**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594235/sparky)

[jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/)

Comment: Ok for the long version. The short version appended validation only for the first element of the list...really don't know why if it's only sintax matter.

Comment: Your second version is incorrect. jQuery Validate's methods require the `.each()` method in this context.  See option 2b in this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9056425/594235

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$.each(elements, function(i, element) {
    $(this).rules('add', {// use $(this) instead of element
    required: true,
    number: true
});
```

or try it **simply**,

```
$("#elementsFieldset :input").rules("add", { 
  required:true,  
  number:true
});
```

You can `add rule` on a `class` See [jQuery Validation using the class instead of the name value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780288/jquery-validation-using-the-class-instead-of-the-name-value)

Comment: Your second version is incorrect. jQuery Validate's methods require the `.each()` method in this context.  See option 2b in this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9056425/594235